# D3 time formatting locale

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js, angular-nvd3

Is possible to return localized information from D3 Time Format?

```
d3.time.format('%B %Y')(new Date(d))
```

This always return EN values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. There is a github wiki page [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Localization).

Basically you need to use `d3.locale(definition)` method. Definition is an object like this:

```
{
  "decimal": ".",
  "thousands": ",",
  "grouping": [3],
  "currency": ["$", ""],
  "dateTime": "%a %b %e %X %Y",
  "date": "%m/%d/%Y",
  "time": "%H:%M:%S",
  "periods": ["AM", "PM"],
  "days": ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"],
  "shortDays": ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"],
  "months": ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
  "shortMonths": ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
}
```

**Update**

> The formatting of numbers, dates and currencies varies by language and locale. While the **default build of D3 is intended for U.S. English**, you can **change the behavior of D3’s formatters by loading new locales** as needed.

So, locale is not gets identified automatically and you should load desired by yourself.

Little example:

```
var ua = d3.locale(<uk_UA definition>); //you need this object to be available everywhere this locale is required
ua.timeFormat('%B %Y'); //use this instead of d3.time.format('%B %Y')
```

Comment: Ok, but locale is not automatically identified? Each locale I have to insert a different difinition object?

Comment: @ieaglle, are _"ready to go"_ definitions exists somewhere? So I do not need to define them all by myself.

Comment: @BohdanKuts, yes they are [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-format/tree/master/locale)

Comment: @ieaglle thanks! Unfortunately there is no month names, weekday names and date format.